# Can't get ToolBar to behave correctly

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm implementing an app with a tool bar using api 31. I have a layout with a green button such that when I long click on the button it is supposed change the search icon to delete and edit icons. Instead it is displaying a white empty toolbar above the original purple toolbar that is in my layout.

Here is the what it looks like before I click the green button:

[image]

and here it is after clicking green button:

[image]

The purple toolbar doesn't change but there is a white bar above with nothing in it.

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainMenuToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setText("  main menu  ");
        myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (mActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }
                myButton.setText(" context menu  ");
                mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_action_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainMenuToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Notes.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bstext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGreen"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="158dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="494dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bstext"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.notes.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_stuff"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

context_action_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Option 1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Option 2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testtoolbarapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyToolBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following style and change your Activity to use it as theme.

```
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: OK this partially resolved my issue. The toolbar stacking problem is fixed, thanks. But it is still changing the toolbar background to white, why?